# Classic ASP DIM with variable possible?

Tags: asp-classic

Any way I could do something like this:

```
x=2
DIM y(x)
```

It doesn't work :-( Problem is I need to define the dimensions of y acording to some result in the page (not like x=2 of course, I could do DIM y(2) then easily). The dimension will NOT change any more on the page. Any other option to do that, only I can think of is using

```
dim y()
redim y(x)
```

Is this bad to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No its not bad; its the correct approach to create a dynamic array given that in VBScript you can only `dim arr(N)` if `N` is a constant integer.